# Why variadic parameters cannot be marked as inout in swift?

Tags: swift, apple-documentation

Apple documentation says,

> "In-out parameters cannot have default values and variadic parameters
>   cannot be marked as inout".

Why we are restricted from doing so?

Comment: I cannot even imagine a use case for such a thing.

Comment: func trim<C: Comparable>(comparables: inout C..., min: C, max: C) {
    for comparable in comparables {
        if comparable < min { comparable = min }
        if comparable > max { comparable = max }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding till now:

We can not pass Constant/Literals to input parameters. Because Constant/Literals are immutable and can not be changed.

But for Variadics, we can pass Constant/Literals as parameters.
So if we can make the Variadics as inout, then it contradicts the above facts.

Regarding default values for Variadic parameter, the default value of Variadic parameter is an empty array. Playground image attached.

[image: Playground Image]

Let me know in case I have an incorrect understanding.

Answer (score -1):

We can not pass Constant/Literals to input parameters. Because Constant/Literals are immutable and can not be changed.

But for Variadics, we can pass Constant/Literals as parameters. So if we can make the Variadics as inout, then it contradicts the above facts.